# trapframe register values for prog name and argv

Tags: registry, exec, execv, os161

I am working with os161 and I want to find register values for char *program name and char **argv to pass to execv system call from traframe structure

trapframe->tf_a1 stores argv values but the datatype of all is u_int32 in trapframe

How can I find them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look under `/src/kern/arch/mips/syscall.c`
In your case, I don't think exec/execv case are implement by default, therefore you need to implement those under

```
void
syscall(struct trapframe *tf)
{
...
switch (callno) {
...
case exec:
something
...
                }
}
```